# Alt+Left Click selecting incorrect faces

Tags: modeling

I am trying to select the faces that wrap around my object like this:

[image]

But i would like to do it for these areas:
[image]

But when I try to do Alt+Left Click, this is the result:
[image]

If I'm lucky, one in ten times, I will get this, which is what I want:
[image]

What buttons/settings am I supposed to press/have to be able to select the faces I want more reliably?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pay attention to the closest edge when you <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to select a loop of faces. The closest edge determines the direction of the loop.

[image: direction mockup]